# momentjs within ionic view cannot find path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I use this repo https://github.com/urish/angular-moment. I install momentjs by running `npm install angular-moment moment --save`. I can see in node_modules folder `angular moment` and `moment` are there.

I then follow the instruction include the js file like this

```
<script src="components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

I also tried

`<script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>`

but still coulnd't load js. I'm using ionic framework aka cordova.

Comment: ok. do a test, move those files near to index.html then add reference like this <script src="moment.js"></script> , check if it works,

Comment: @rashidnk it doesn't work like that in cordova

Comment: you have no cordova www folder??